# Show a page header only if there is data on the page

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a suppression formula that shows my page header only on the first page with data (which is not necessarily the first page of the report), and hides it afterward. I'm using a flag to suppress the page header after it's been shown once, so that part shouldn't be any trouble.

The tricky part is counting what's on the page. Sounds simple, but these things don't work:

1) A Running Total, because it's evaluated after the page's records are printed so its count doesn't show up until the next page.

2) A "Count" formula, because it counts every record in the report, not just on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about the fields on the report? Check if they contain data, and if not, suppress the header.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do - count a field if it contains data to determine whether the page has data. But how do I get the count for the data in the page I'm on to the header of the same page?

Comment: Well, you would have to use WhilePrintingRecords I think.

Comment: Yep tried that; didn't do the trick.

Comment: Could you post a screeenshot of your report structure, please?

Comment: Sorry, can't do that. Company's touchy. Basically it's: PH GH Details PF. Need to see if there's data in the Details section to determine whether to suppress the PH.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, campagnolo_1.

Answer (score 1):

Think I got it. Might be overly complicated but this is what seems to be working (note I didn't use a count after all).

This goes in an always-suppressed formula in the Details section that, if shown, I want to see the Page Header (but only once, as stated in the question):

```
whileprintingrecords;
global booleanvar ShowPageHeader := true
```

Then this goes in the suppression formula for the Page Header:

```
whileprintingrecords;
global booleanvar PageHeaderAlreadyShown;
global booleanvar ShowPageHeader;

if PageHeaderAlreadyShown then
    true
else if ShowPageHeader then
(
    PageHeaderAlreadyShown := true;
    false
)
else
    true
```

The "PageHeaderAlreadyShown" flag hides the page header after it's been shown once.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing any of your fields, you would probably be able to use something like:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
{table.field} = ""
```

That should suppress it if a certain field has no data.